# nginx config: How to forward to different ports based on URL parameter?

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx. Below is what I want:

```
http://example.com/3000/lorem/ipsum -> http://example.com:3000/lorem/ipsum
http://example.com/3001/lorem/ipsum -> http://example.com:3001/lorem/ipsum
http://example.com/3002/lorem/ipsum -> http://example.com:3002/lorem/ipsum
```

I have done something so it works but I think there are better ways:

```
location /3000/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /3001/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /3002/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I have read many posts to solve this by using regex but I cannot figure out how exactly the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below fixed the problem:

```
location ~ ^/300(0|1|2) {
    rewrite ^/300(0|1|2)(/?)(.*) /$3 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:300$1;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
location ~ /(300[0-2])(/|)(\S+|)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1/$3;
}
```

Please note that it can cause problems if the port number is not on the leftmost side in the URI like: ***example.com/lorem/ipsum/3000.html*** will be proxied to ***localhost:3000/lorem/ipsum/.html*** which is rubbish of course.